# Can't move Command Prompt to another virtual desktop?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, virtual-desktop

I can successfully move any window across virtual desktops, by using WIN+ALT+RIGHTARROW.

However, this doesn't work for Command Prompt. Why not?

Comment: Can you open the overview, and drag it to the other desktop from there though? That will tell you if somehow CMD catches the key internally rather than passing it through to windows.

Comment: @LPChip Yes, that works. It only fails when I use the hotkey method, or when I use the right click method like this: https://imgur.com/a/L15U30E